# IMobileServiceTableQuery does not send correct parameters to server

Tags: azure, xamarin, f#, azure-mobile-services

I have this function, that sends queries down to my Azure Mobile servce:

```
let pullTable<'a when 'a :> EntityDto> (logger: ILog) (table: Sync.IMobileServiceSyncTable<'a>) (tableQuery: IMobileServiceTableQuery<'a>) =
    async {
        match CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected with
        | false -> ()
        | true ->
            try 
                do! table.PullAsync (Unchecked.defaultof<string>, tableQuery) |> Async.AwaitTask
            with 
                | ex -> logger.Warning Tag (sprintf "Transient error: Connection failure") (Some ex)
    }
```

It is called from this method:

```
member this.GetVenuesAsync managerId =
    async {
        do! initialiseSyncContext mobileServiceClient
        let table = mobileServiceClient.GetSyncTable<VenueDto>()
        do! pullTable logger table (table.Where(fun v -> v.ManagerId = managerId))
        let! results = table.ToEnumerableAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
        return results |> Array.ofSeq
    }
```

Unfortunately, the `Where` clause in this method is completely ineffectual: it brings back all of the venues.

Stopping the server at the endpoint, no filter has been added to the Odata query generated by `table.PullAsync`. This looks like a bug to me.

1. Have I made a mistake somewhere?
2. If this is a bug,
   i. Are there any workarounds?
   ii. Is there a place to report it?

**EDIT 1**: I have also tried this variation, with no success:

```
member this.GetVenuesAsync managerId =
    async {
        do! initialiseSyncContext mobileServiceClient
        let table = mobileServiceClient.GetSyncTable<VenueDto>()
        do! pullTable logger table (table.CreateQuery())
        let! results = table.Where(fun v -> v.ManagerId = managerId).ToEnumerableAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
        return results |> Array.ofSeq
    }
```

**EDIT 2**: Bruce Chen's answer was a partial solution, but it has highlighted another problem, which I believe is F# specific. With

```
do! pullTable logger table (table.CreateQuery().Where(fun v -> v.ManagerId = managerId))
```

The endpoint does indeed pick up the filter, but the filter is unfortunately in the wrong format. At my `TableController`'s endpoint

```
[EnableQuery] public IHttpActionResult Get() => Ok(Query());
```

the `RequestUrl` has a query string containing `$filter=(managerId%20eq%202L)`. This L suffix is a problem: `managerId` is defined as an `int`, not a `long`. But the odata endpoint interprets it as a `long`. I don't know if there is an easy way to fix this.

Comment: I responded to your flag, but you might not see that. The reason why you can't rename [azure-mobile-services] to [azure-mobile-app] is that the latter has been set as a synonym of the former: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-mobile-services/synonyms and is automatically remapped by the system. If you feel that is incorrect, I encourage you to make an argument for it on Meta and explain why the two should be separated. I don't know enough about the topic to make a call here.

Comment: Azure Mobile Services has been deprecated, and replaced by Azure Mobile apps.

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, you could try to change your code as follows for pulling records from the remote Venue table with the specific `ManagerId` via the `PullAsync` method.

```
do! pullTable logger table (table.CreateQuery())

//To

do! pullTable logger table (table.CreateQuery().Where(fun v -> v.ManagerId = managerId))
```

Here is the [tutorial](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#query-management) for pulling records with filters wrote in C#, you could refer to it and check with your code.

Comment: That has got me a part of the way there, but there is another problem -- see my second edit. I will continue to investigate this and report back with any findings.

Comment: I checked with my UWP client, I could retrieve the same result. Per my understanding, since your `ManagerId` is defined as int32, the data type in your db table could be bigint or int, at this point the odata transform does not affect your query. But when the ManagerId is defined as int64 in your client side, the data type in your db table should be bigint.

Comment: Somehow, my IMobileServiceClient is generating the suffix, so the actual DB table is not relevant. I believe it's something to do with the `SerializerSettings` of the `IMobileServiceClient` instance. I tried adding a JsonConverter that converted `Int32` instances, but for some reason that wasn't picked up by the serializer.